# Can the deep learning model do the training and testing stages using different length of output

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

As I know, the deep learning model does the training for such inputs to produce an output, then that trained model will be used to predict the output based on the novel input which has the same length of input used in the training stage, also the predicted output has the same length of vector used in training stage. My concern is little bit different.
When having a deep learning model, assume the input to be a vector y with length N, and the output x with length M. Can the deep learning model do the training for the input vector y till some values of x are correct, then the deep learning model will be used to predict the other values of x? How can we do that process, I mean which process can be followed in that case?

For example, I have random vector y with size 50 x 1, and the output x a vector x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]. So can the deep learning use the vector y and do the training till have the first four values of x to be [0,1,2,3], then we let the trained model to predict the other values of the vector x. It is very important to mention there that values of the output vector depends on each other, so expecting part of them can yield the other values too.

I tried to follow the conventional way to do that, but I find that same size of input/outputs during the training and testing stages must be used while what I am looking for is little bit different.

Comment: Two scenarios: a) If you have such a strong dependency between the values (a function for example), you could train the classifier to only predict parts of your output in the first place, since the rest of the sequence of x is determined already (it is just redundant information). b) If there is still "wiggle room" for the following values of x, given the first elements, you could write a second classifier that starts with parts of x as the input, predicting the rest of the sequence.

Comment: @Baradrist Could you please add more details; I couldn't get how will be the two scenarios you suggested.

Comment: You mentioned:
"It is very important to mention there that values of the output vector depends on each other, so expecting part of them can yield the other values too."

So there is a relation between the entries in x, right? Now the question becomes: Is this relation deterministic (aka a function) or is it only correlated/linked in some unknown way? In the first case, you only need to know the function and it is sufficient to predict only parts of your x-vector. If the second is the case, you could try and write a predictor from "small x" to the whole x-vector. Did that clarify?

Comment: @Baradrist It is little bit clearer now, My situation is similar to the second case. What do you mean write a predictor from "small x" to the whole x-vector?  Is it using deep learning too?

Comment: Yes, just take the first x as the input for a new classifier and learn it to predict the rest of the vector. If there is a functional relationship and you have a sufficient data (which should be the case for your first classifier anyways), the classifier should be able to predict it. Then you can just make a pipeline of the two. Keep in mind that with the second step, your metric might worsen. But this is to be expected with what you had in mind as well.